# Custom error page - get originally requested URL

Tags: jsf, servlets, http-status-code-404

**Problem**

This is a follow-up to yesterday's (unanswered) question ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240770/jsf-urlrewritefilter-catchall-404-replacement)) as I try to find an alternative approach.

I added the basic

```
    <error-page>  
            <error-code>404</error-code>  
            <location>/404search.jsf</location>  
    </error-page>
```

..to my `web.xml`. I now need to get the URL the user entered to submit to my search function, but I only manage to get the current URL (in this case, ...`404search.jsf`) instead of the actual query the user entered.

**Attempts**

- `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL` returns `http://www.website.com/foldername/404search.jsf`
- `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI` returns `/foldername/404search.jsf`
- `HttpServletRequest.getQueryString` returns nothing at all

I want it to return `/foldername/wrong-url-the-user-entered#anchor-if-there-is-any`

**Details...**

The idea is to get the URL the user entered (such as `www.site.com/product/99999-product-that-cant-be-found` or `www.site.com/faq/support-question-that-doesnt-exist`), REGEX it to remove the hyphens and run a search query with `99999 product that cant be found` or `support question that doesnt exist`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `<error-page>` is under the covers served by a [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/apidocs/jakarta.servlet/jakarta/servlet/requestdispatcher#forward(jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest,jakarta.servlet.ServletResponse)) call. All details of the original request are available as request attribues which are keyed by the keys as identified by [`RequestDispatcher#ERROR_XXX`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/apidocs/jakarta.servlet/jakarta/servlet/requestdispatcher#ERROR_EXCEPTION) constants:

- [`ERROR_EXCEPTION`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/apidocs/jakarta.servlet/jakarta/servlet/requestdispatcher#ERROR_EXCEPTION): `"jakarta.servlet.error.exception"`
- [`ERROR_EXCEPTION_TYPE`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/apidocs/jakarta.servlet/jakarta/servlet/requestdispatcher#ERROR_EXCEPTION_TYPE): `"jakarta.servlet.error.exception_type"`
- [`ERROR_MESSAGE`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/apidocs/jakarta.servlet/jakarta/servlet/requestdispatcher#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI): `"jakarta.servlet.error.message"`
- [`ERROR_REQUEST_URI`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/apidocs/jakarta.servlet/jakarta/servlet/requestdispatcher#ERROR_REQUEST_URI): `"jakarta.servlet.error.request_uri"`
- [`ERROR_SERVLET_NAME`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/apidocs/jakarta.servlet/jakarta/servlet/requestdispatcher#ERROR_SERVLET_NAME): `"jakarta.servlet.error.servlet_name"`
- [`ERROR_STATUS_CODE`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/apidocs/jakarta.servlet/jakarta/servlet/requestdispatcher#ERROR_STATUS_CODE): `"jakarta.servlet.error.status_code"`

*(note: if you're still not on Jakarta EE 9 or newer, use `javax.*` instead of `jakarta.*`)*

All request attributes are in EL available via the [implicit EL object](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects) `#{requestScope}`.

So, all with all, this should do in the view:

```html
<p>Unfortunately, the page you requested, #{requestScope['jakarta.servlet.error.request_uri']} does not exist</p>
```

And equivalently, this should do in the bean, if necessary:

```
String errorRequestURI = externalContext.getRequestMap().get(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_REQUEST_URI);
```

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to get that URL with the "referer" (misspelled) request header.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36

Java usage: [HttpServletRequest - how to obtain the referring URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648984/httpservletrequest-how-to-obtain-the-referring-url)